# converting opj files to a readable file format in ubuntu

Tags: windows, file-format, convert

I used to work in Microsoft Windows and lots of my data are in `opj` format from [`Origin`](http://www.originlab.com/viewer/). I deeply searched to find a way to convert my files in Linux but I found almost nothing to work. Do you have any idea?

Regards.

Comment: I found the `opj2dat` package but there is no guide or man page and I couldn't work with it.

Comment: This readme in liborigin's github page seems useful. https://sourceforge.net/p/liborigin/git/ci/master/tree/  
I see lots of recent updates in their github--one was just yesterday, 2018-04-07.

If you can still access Origin temporarily, perhaps at work or in a VM, then you could try using Origin's Mathematica Link. It allows you to import/export data from/to Mathematica. Once it's in Mathematica, you have lots of options of what to do with the data. https://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/Mathematica-Procedure-EX

Answer (score 1):

The best and simplest is to download [SciDAVis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciDAVis), which is both gratis & libre (GPLv2). You can read and manipulate .opj files just like in Origin. Download from [here](https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3Ahpcoder1&package=scidavis), or build from [source](https://github.com/highperformancecoder/scidavis).

Another option is to build [liborigin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/liborigin/), also gratis & libre (GPLv2). When you run the script like `opj2dat ./foo.opj` it exports all the data tables to separate plain text files.

Finally you also could use [QtiPlot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QtiPlot), but you need the paid "Pro" version to actually deal with .opj files...